What does "ways" in "Canada ways" mean here?
This context comes from the movie "The Lighthouse". It's a conversation between two keepers of a lighthouse who work together. It

"What brings you to this rock, Ephraim Winslow? What were yer work afore?"
"Timber."
"Timber..."
"Big timber. Up north. Canada ways."
"Hudson Bay outfit?"

Seems like he's specifying a location in Canada but the only definition I was able to find that would fit the context is:
way (noun):

a direction or vicinity: There's a drought out our way.
(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010)

But Hudson Bay is IN Canada and not in the vicinity of it.

The conversation is taking place at a lighthouse in Maine, New England, the USA - not in Canada.

@MichaelHarvey - This text is could be referring to the same Hudson's Bay Company, which was the royally-chartered corporation in charge of all British trade and commerce in Rupert's Land (now north-central Canada) from the 17th century onwards. "Hudson Bay outfit" could very well mean "a timber operation run by the HBC".

@CanadianYankee Yes, and a long way from the Maine coast, most likely.

@Michael Harvey I found this definition on Collins dictionary. Is this the usage in this case? 17. Informal a district; locality; area out our way

'Canada ways' simply means, in American New England dialect, 'in, near, or in the direction of  Canada' You are reproducing dialect speech, and my guess is that the speaker is intended to be American. (Update: in a lighthouse in Maine, USA - thanks, Ronald Sole!) In informal speech we can append 'way' or (even more dialectic) 'ways' to a region, place, country, etc, to mean 'in the direction or location of' the place in question.
A 1939 song is called South Of The Border (Down Mexico Way); a 1941 film was called Down Mexico Way.
It is common in the UK to hear people saying informal things like 'He lives over/down/up Croydon way'

While growing up in south London, I knew people who lived both 'down Purley Way' and also 'down Purley way', and some of whom only the first was true, and of some only the second. None of them were goers, in case anyone is curious.

Actually, it doesn't mean that in American English in the plural. It (a ways) means pretty far from a place.

@Lambie - Down the road a ways, or (thanks to the Rolling Stones c. 1965) down the road a piece, yes, pretty far. So would you say 'Up North. Canada ways' means 'North of here, a long way away in Canada'?

Yes, and that can mean a long ways.

This answer is simply not accurate. Sorry.

This answer is simply good and thorough :)

The dictionary definition you found is correct and applies in this case.
"Canada ways" means "in the vicinity of Canada". And yes, Canada itself is in the vicinity of Canada for this purpose.
Also be aware that "Hudson bay outfit" ( "Hudson's Bay" would be the correct name) might mean the Hudson's Bay company, which used to operate many places other than Hudson's Bay, or another company headquartered near Hudson's Bay. It doesn't necessarily mean he was working near Hudson's Bay.

According to Wright's English Dialect Dictionary (Oxford),  way, often plural, ways, when preceded by a place-name, means in the direction of, towards the named place.
The boundary between Canada and Maine was disputed and wasn't settled officially until the middle of the 19th-century, and in a remote virgin forest wilderness the exact location of the border between Maine and Canada could be somewhat "hazy" in the minds of  seasonal laborers in the logging industry. These seasonal laborers worked both sides of the border, going wherever men were needed, often logging in disputed areas; it was expedient to ignore things like international boundaries.  Large companies also set up "black market" logging operations, skirting regulations.

In AmE colloquial English, you hear:
"It's a ways down the road", for example.
Here's a tweet from X where it is used metaphorically:
hey
@SGJ72
what's the best way to get a signed copy of The Buffalo Hunter Hunter? I know it's a ways down the road. I want to pre-order, but not sure if you're coming to Chicago, or if you'll have a dedicated bookstore handling signings. Congrats, man, it looks amazing. You're really filling out my SGJ shelf LOL.
a ways down the road
Here is a  literal one:
Look for a large, deep natural drainage down off the right side of the road - it's a ways down the road. Start hiking uphill just past this drainage. Go uphill through trees and mossy boulders until you reach an old roadbed that runs parallel to Highway 41.
climbing in Yosemite Park
Also, in AmE, and other Englishes too, way can mean place, as described in Michael's answer. And here it means a long distance into Canada. Writers try to avoid clichés and sometimes they take an existing expression like (down the road a ways) and transform it as these writers did. A ways [up] into Canada [from Maine], might have been a bit better. Because Hudson Bay, Canada is pretty far from the coast of Maine where the imaginary lighthouse was located. It is the context of Maine, the coast of Maine and the distance to Canada's Hudson Bay that makes it clear that it means long way away from the characters.

A ways up/down/along the road are all common in the sense of a certain distance. It means not close.

Q: Am I close to the river?

Ans: No, you still have a ways to go. [a good distance to go.]


Merriam Webster
a ways to go
noun phrase
US, informal
: a long distance to go
We still have a ways to go before we're home.
—often used figuratively
We've done a lot of work on this project, but we have a long ways to go.
She still has a ways to go before graduation.
a ways

@StaticBounce Why are you asking Michael under my answer? The Merriam Webster is best for American English.  Also, Collins has AmE and BrE things.

I don't think this is correct and think it's a bit misleading. "A ways" is a distance. "How far are we?" "Still a ways away yet". "Up canada ways" is a direction.

@Kaia "Canada ways" means "a ways up into Canada". "Big timber. Up north. Canada ways". The other speaker even asks him"Hudson Bay outfit?" which makes it far away. Not close.

And he answers: Big timber. Up north. Canada ways.
OLD
Hudson Bay outfit?
YOUNG
The same. || So, he did mean far away.||This usage is creative by the authors.
